# How to post data via ajax to a python script?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I've an HTML Page which send value to a Python script. I want to receive the values of the data send and also ensure that the script is running everytime so as the data can received mutiple times. how would I do that?

My Jquery is

```
$(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type : "POST",
                    url: "/tcp_driver.py",
                    data : { 'count_query' : 'count_query', 'start_time' : start_time, 'end_time' : end_time, 'last_time' : last_time},

                    success : function(result){
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I want to connect my HTML page with a python code. How would I do that? How would I keep my python code listening? kindly guide me or point towards a resource where I can read on it. Thanks

Comment: You can search on net for **python webservice*, there are tool like DJango, WebPy, pecan etc.. available. Select which is comfirtable for you.

Comment: Cant I do it with single Python script? Is it a requirement for this particular use-case.

Comment: I'm reading about CGI scripts. Is it a solution for the same? PS: tried that but not working as per my requirements.

Comment: I am not aware about CGI bu u can use DJango its simple. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

There are many python web frameworks such as `Flask`, `Django`. My recommendatian is to start with [Flask Framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It is very simple and easy to start.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/message")
def message():
    // Handle your post message
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I dont want to use any frameworks. What I want is that there is one python code which should be listening all the times. How will I do that?

Comment: If you made this decision because of not knowing the frameworks, then i can strongly suggest you to learn some framework. If you have any other good reason not using frameworks, then you can checkout this stackoverflow question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596729/how-do-i-use-python-for-web-development-without-relying-on-a-framework